# PHP memcache internal objects

Tags: php, dom, memcached

I have googling for a while and found nothing.

When dealing with internal objects such as DOM or PDO, is it possible to cache them using memcache?

I understand that PDO would likely be irrelevant because the connection is closed at end of script - this could be changed to persistent connections -- making caching more feasible???

Whats really bothering me though, is the lack of documentation on whether its possible to cache the in-memory representation of DOM objects. XML config files could be quite verbose and loading these per request, constructing the DOM, would probably way heavily on the server resources.

Anyone have any experience with caching, specifically DOM objects? Should I opt for a PHP implementation of a DOM just so re-parsing, initializing the DOM isn't necessary each request?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache a PDO instance. You will have to extend the PDO class and implement the `__wakeup` and `__sleep` magic method.

The `__sleep()` method will be called before `serialize()` and the `__wakeup` during `unserialize()` (it's not precised when on the manual).

You would use the `__wakeup` method to reestablish the connection after unserialization by Memcache.

I don't think there is a lot of interest in caching a PDO instance.

Most core objects cannot be cached. This is because they are not serialized properly. Only instances of classes implementing the `Serializable` interface can be.

Maybe in some cases it can work, if the class has only public properties.

Comment: The worry I have with caching something like a DB Connection (this is thus something connecting to a third party) is that the logic to figure things out like "does the connection exist" most likely sits in the constructor of the (in this case) PDO class. This means that, say you unserialise the object, the question is... does the unserialise() function handle these edge cases or not? If it doesn't, you're in for nasty surprises. Personally, I'd rather not. What is your major reason for trying to cache it, do you have a large enough performance gain in caching something like this?

Comment: The serialize / unserialize functions doesn't handle edge cases. You need to define how your objects can be serialized by implementing the Serializable interface, or if they can be correctly serialized let's say if they have only public properties, you will implement the __wakeup method to reestablish the connection yourself. I don't think either caching a PDO instance can lead in any performance gain. What you want to cache are big data structures or big strings that needs processing time to be generated.

Comment: I shouldn't have mentioned PDO at all, my interest is in caching XML due to the overhead of loading/parsing large XML files; whether they be config or templates for some other function such as templating.